# google sheets copy file to subfolder with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

google sheets copy file to subfolder with script

I want to make a copy of a google spreadsheet to a specific subfolder with a sript/makro, but
the following code from the makro recorder always save the file in the root folder
The new folder name is the value of A7.

```
function TTB_kopieren() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A7').activate();
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("A7").getDisplayValue();
  spreadsheet.copy(myValue);
};
```

Thanks!